# Extracting items which occur over n times in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Say I'm using R and have a data table:

```
x <- data.table(V1 = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D"))    
table(x)
```

gives the following:

```
A B C D     
3 2 1 1
```

How do I extract the items which occur over n times? For example, the output should be "A" if n = 2, and "A" and "B" if n = 1, and "A", "B", "C" if n = 0.

Comment: Since  you are using `data.table` `x[, V1[.N > 1], V1]$V1`

Comment: Or `x[, .N, V1][N>1, V1]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `names(x)[x > n]`, where `n` is the desired number of times. For example, `names(x)[x > 1]` gives `"A" "B"`